# Exibir regiões com Google Geochart

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google, google-charts

É possível exibir os estados agrupados de acordo com suas regiões e uma tooltip de acordo com a região e não com o estado?
Por exemplo:

- Região Norte -> Acre, Amapá, Amazonas, Pará, Rondônia, Roraima, Tocantins
- Região Sul -> Paraná, Rio Grande do Sul, Santa Catarina
- ...

A região norte quando selecionada, abordaria todos os estados listados e uma unica descrição.

Utilizo este código para estados, porém, não consegui retirar da api algo referente a minha dúvida.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
        'packages': ['geochart']
    });

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

    function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Region','Views'],
            ['Acre', 0],
            ['Alagoas', 1],
            ['Amapá', 2],
            ['Amazonas', 3],
            ['Bahia', 4],
            ['Ceará', 1],
            ['Distrito Federal', 2],
            ['Espírito Santo', 3],
            ['Goiás', 0],
            ['Maranhão', 5],
            ['Mato Grosso', 0],
            ['Mato Grosso do Sul', 1],
            ['Minas Gerais', 2],
            ['Pará', 3],
            ['Paraíba', 4],
            ['Paraná', 3],
            ['Pernambuco', 2],
            ['Piauí', 4],
            ['Rio de Janeiro', 1],
            ['Rio Grande do Norte', 0],
            ['Rio Grande do Sul', 1],
            ['Rondônia', 5],
            ['Roraima', 2],
            ['Santa Catarina', 4],
            ['São Paulo', 3],
            ['Sergipe', 2],
            ['Tocantins', 0]
        ]);

        var options = {
            region: 'BR',
            resolution: 'provinces',
            colorAxis: {
                values: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                colors: ['red', 'black', 'purple', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']
            },
            datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
            legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: Talvez seja, você deve fazer uma busca, por algo que busca região sul / nordeste por exemplo: `\"geometry" : {
     "bounds" : {
     "northeast" : {
       "lat" : -26.1965843,
       "lng" : -52.6890572
     },
   "southwest" : {
     "lat" : -26.1966978,
     "lng" : -52.6892667
   }`: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?hl=pt

Comment: O google tem um modelo de query que pega através do raio, algo similar a isso numa consulta dos seus dados ou unidades que possuirem coordenadas:

`SELECT * , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$latitude') ) * cos( radians( nr_lat ) ) * cos( radians( nr_long ) - radians('$longitude') ) + sin( radians('$latitude') ) * sin( radians( nr_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM tabela_unidades WHERE status = 1 HAVING distance < 50`

Comment: Acredito que o que você esteja querendo fazer, é "desenhar" no mapa as regiões. O Google sozinho, até onde sei não é capaz de fazer isto, mas você pode desenhar a região que deseja com poligonos no mapa. O google vai ter um mapa por região, separado, exemplo: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Regi%C3%A3o+Nordeste+do+Brasil/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x71604fcb37bd619:0x7d035aee7f1710c6?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM2_XI3L_wAhVuI7kGHaMaC4MQ8gEwAHoECAYQAQ Trabalhando com polignos
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon Você teria que ter todos pontos em uma matrix, e depois gerar

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar a opção `region` do GeoChart, tipo isso:

```js
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  ['Region','State'],
  ['Norte', 'Acre'],
  ['Norte', 'Amapá'],
  ['Norte', 'Amazonas'],
  ['Norte', 'Pará'],
  ['Norte', 'Rondônia'],
  ['Norte', 'Roraima'],
  ['Norte', 'Tocantins'],
  ['Sul', 'Paraná'],
  ['Sul', 'Rio Grande do Sul'],
  ['Sul', 'Santa Catarina'],
  // ...
]);

var options = {
  region: 'BR', // <- aqui
  resolution: 'provinces',
  colorAxis: {colors: ['#f1c40f', '#e67e22']},
  legend: 'none',
  datalessRegionColor: '#ECECEC',
  defaultColor: '#F5F5F5',
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'none'
  }
};
```

Refs:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference